# Query selector for element having specific child

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, selectors-api

Soo basically I want to select element which has specific child elements. For now I have selector which selects the child element of a chain:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#leftMenu ul > li > a:not(.active) + ul > li.active')
```

Now to get the element I'm interested in i have to do this:

```
const x = el.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Is there any way to get this element staight from the selector itself?

Comment: if you'd use jQuery syntax, it could be possible to get it in one line.

Comment: True, life would be so much easier :) But unfortunately I can't use jquery.

Answer (score 3):

In [Chrome 105+](https://caniuse.com/css-has) you can use the `:has` pseudo selector:

```js
document.querySelector(`a:has(b)`).style.color = 'red'
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<a><b>2</b></a>
<a>3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent selector,
However it should be [available in CSS level 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811495/is-parent-selector-available-in-css4), which is a long way from being implemented.

So, the best thing you can do is to add in one line:
`const el = document.querySelector('#leftMenu ul > li > a:not(.active) + ul > li.active').parentNode.parentNode;`

Comment: Wow, didn't think of it... Like seriously man, it doesn't even partially answering my question.

Ok after edit at least it contains some meaningful information.

Comment: @pol, this is actually pretty smart.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to select a parent (i.e. an element with specified children). See [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

There may be one in the future, but currently, your method looks like the best solution.